# Why my bootstrap columns are not at center at smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning bootstrap.
I want to display a list in central 8 columns at large screens and to span all 12 columns on smaller screens.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- projects tab -->
    <div class="projects" id="projects">
        <div class="container-fluid projects">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    
    font-family: "Raleway";
}

.projects {
    margin: 10em;
    position: relative;
}
```

But, the list gets rendered right:
[image]

[image]
Why is this so?

Comment: your CSS link seems wrong: you have 2 different stylesheets but with not rule connected to them. you need to use for the first: "<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />" and for the second: "<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-device-width: 481px)' href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you consider using `-sm` prefix instead of `-lg`, because you probably wants to render it differently on smartphones, but if you really wanna render like this only for lg ok.

Second, try to inspect it and see where the space is coming from, it may be coming from your own projects class.

**Edit:** also, there is no need to use position relative on your projects class, you need to organize the content with bootstrap col classes

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<!-- projects tab -->
<div class="projects" id="projects">
    <div class="container-fluid projects">
```

You used `projects` class twice. Remove it from the second div and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-lg-1"></div> // left
<div class="col-lg-7"></div> // middle
<div class="col-lg-4"></div> // right
```

Here is the problem; you need to divide columns evenly from `left` and `right`

`col-lg-1` `col-lg-4` are not same. keep it same for `left` and `right`

Too much margin - `margin: 10em` will be too much for small screen. try `margin: 10em 0`

Main changes:

```html
<div class="col-lg-2">..</div> // left
<div class="col-lg-8">..</div> // middle
<div class="col-lg-2">..</div> // right
```

```css
projects: {
margin: 10em 0;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is fixed code:

```css
.body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: &quot;
  Raleway&quot;
  ;
  justify-content: center;
}

.projects {
  margin: 10em 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <!-- projects tab -->
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
    <div class="container-fluid projects">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <ol>
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
              in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </li>
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
              in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```